# how check in code in two differents vcs

Tags: git, svn, version-control, dvcs

Imagine you are working on some code, that needs to be checked into the 'official vcs' (A). But you also want to check the code into your own vcs (B).

A (this can be SVN or git) and B (git).  I will need to pull changes from A, but not from B (B is for my own use only).

What is the best way to solve this?

I am thinking of some checking into A, and using an Ant target to copy the src to a clean directory and check in that one into B, so I can pull changes easily from A.

Is that the best way? Anyone dealing with this already and having some advise?

thanks

Comment: Will B be used by someone beside yourself?

Comment: Which VCSs these are is very important: git brings a tool called [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) which interfaces a git repo (yours) with an svn repo (upstream).

Comment: edited question with replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need `B` to be a remote repo?

In `git`, you work on your own repo, that usually is a clone of a remote repo. So, it's a **full** repository. You commit to it, you checkout branches from it. And you connect it with other repositories for synchronizing commits.

If you don't need `B` to be a remote repository, you can just [`git clone`](http://learn.github.com/p/remotes.html) a remote git repository, or [`git svn clone`](http://learn.github.com/p/git-svn.html) a remote SVN repository. Then, you'll have two repositories, that would be synchronized as you `pull`/`push`/`dcommit`/`rebase`.

If you need your `B` repository to be remote, you can always add another remote with `git remote add` and `push`/`pull` to/from it, independently of when you synchronize with `A` repo, independently of `A` repo being git or SVN.

Answer (score 0):

If both A and B are git, your repo can have multiple remotes.

For example:

```
$ git push origin
$ git remote add myPrivateRepo /path/to/the/private/repository
$ git push myPrivateRepo
```

Answer (score 0):

Git + git-svn

"Own" VCS is **local** Git-repo, for external Subversion you just add Subversion-remote